# Dataflow to set BigQuery partition based on the data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How could I configure Dataflow to set BigQuery table partition dynamically - based on the incoming data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I took is following:

- Set the window for the incoming record
- Convert the window into the table name

  ```
  p.apply(PubsubIO.Read
              .subscription(subscription)
              .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
          )
          .apply(Window.into(new TablePartitionWindowFn()) )
          .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                         .to(new DayPartitionFunc(dataset, table))
                         .withSchema(schema)
                         .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
          );
  ```

Setting the window based on the incoming data, the end Instant can be ignored, as the start value is used to set the partition:

```
public class TablePartitionWindowFn extends NonMergingWindowFn<Object, IntervalWindow> {

private IntervalWindow assignWindow(AssignContext context) {
    TableRow source = (TableRow) context.element();
    String dttm_str = (String) source.get("DTTM");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZoneUTC();

    Instant start_point = Instant.parse(dttm_str,formatter);
    Instant end_point = start_point.withDurationAdded(1000, 1);

    return new IntervalWindow(start_point, end_point);
};
```

Setting the table partition dynamically:

```
public class DayPartitionFunc implements SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String> {

String destination = "";

public DayPartitionFunc(String dataset, String table) {
    this.destination = dataset + "." + table+ "$";
}

@Override
public String apply(BoundedWindow boundedWindow) {
    // The cast below is safe because CalendarWindows.days(1) produces IntervalWindows.
    String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                                     .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
                                     .print(((IntervalWindow) boundedWindow).start());
    return destination + dayString;
}}
```

Let me know if there is a better way of achieving the same outcome.